# SQL DISTINCT not working in joins, keep getting duplicates. how do i fix this?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT order_updates.order_id as 'order', date, 
sum(products.price*amount), status_id 
FROM order_updates 
LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.id=order_updates.order_id 
JOIN order_items ON orders.id = order_items.order_id 
JOIN products ON products.id = order_items.id 
GROUP by order_updates.id  
ORDER BY order_updates.status_id  ASC
```

above is my SQL code that i use. However i keep getting duplicates.. see below..
Why does this happen?

```
order | date              | sum(products.price*amount | status_id
------------------------------------------------------------------
1     |2018-10-15 17:45:41|46.80000114440918          |1
2     |2018-10-15 17:45:41|21.800000190734863         |1
1     |2018-10-15 17:45:41|46.80000114440918          |3
```

I expect this output:

```
order | date              | sum(products.price*amount | status_id
------------------------------------------------------------------
2     |2018-10-15 17:45:41|21.800000190734863         |1
1     |2018-10-15 17:45:41|46.80000114440918          |3
```

Comment: Your query is **wrong**. If you do `LEFT JOIN` then you cannot use `orders.id` in an inner join. That defeats the purpose of the left join. Do you need a `LEFT JOIN` or not?

Comment: Where's the duplicate? The 3 rows that you pasted are different. 'DISTINCT' works on the whole row, so ideally your query is not returning duplicates as some or the other value is changing in each row.

Comment: @MayankPorwal Really? i didn't know. Is this possible to fix using only SQL?

Comment: First tell me,how do you figure duplicates in the dataset? Also, please share your expected output, that'll make us understand the question better.

Comment: @MayankPorwal as you can see, i get two rows with 1 as order value.

Comment: Please tell us what an order_update is. Why is it in your query? Then please edit your request and qualify all columns with their table, e.g. `order_items.amount` instead of `amount`.

Comment: Two rows with `1` as `order` have different `status_id`, so, which one do you want to pick? See my point, they are not duplicates. :)

Comment: Why are you using a LEFT JOIN? What are you expecting such use to accomplish?

Comment: @MayankPorwal i want to pick the distinct order_id's, and return the highest status_id if that answers your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your expected output you can try this:

```
Select order, date, tot,max(status_id)
from 
(SELECT DISTINCT order_updates.order_id as 'order', date, 
sum(products.price*amount) as tot, status_id 
FROM order_updates 
LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.id=order_updates.order_id 
JOIN order_items ON orders.id = order_items.order_id 
JOIN products ON products.id = order_items.id 
GROUP by order_updates.id  
ORDER BY order_updates.status_id  ASC
)a
group by order,date, tot
```

Comment: unfortunately this doesnt work as i dont use that mysql version

Answer (score 3):

None of those are duplicates; DISTINCT covers the whole row. The first and third rows in your example have different `status_id` values.

Also

- having DISTINCT and a GROUP BY is not usually, if ever, a good idea.
- partial GROUP BYs (that do not cover all non-aggregated fields) are not allowed in many RDBMS and configured as disabled by default in recent MySQL releases. If there is more than one value for any of `order_updates.order_id` `date`, or `status_id` for the same `order_updates.id`, then you will effectively get a random selection of the values encountered for those fields.

Comment: can you elaborate? sorry im really new to sql

Comment: DISTINCT is used for when you want to remove true duplicate rows; a normal GROUP BY should be incapable of producing duplicate rows. By "normal" I mean no `ROLLUP` options, and the grouping fields included in the SELECT list. While it is possible to group on fields not included in the select, I'd say the situations where using DISTINCT on such a query are so rare as to consider any such query suspect.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you want:

```
SELECT o.order_id, o.date, max(status_id),
       sum(p.price * oi.amount)
FROM order_updates ou JOIN
     orders o
     ON o.id = ou.order_id JOIN
     order_items oi
     ON o.id = oi.order_id JOIN
     products p
     ON p.id = oi.id 
GROUP by o.id, o.date 
ORDER BY ou.status_id ASC;
```

Notes:

- All unaggregated columns in the `SELECT` are in the `GROUP BY`.
- The query uses table aliases, so it is easier to write and to read.
- I presume that all order in `order_updates` are in `orders`, so I changes the `left join` to an `inner join`.
- I removed status id from the `group by`, because it is different on different rows.

Presumably, your multiple results are due to the fact that `order_updates.id` is used in the `group by`.  I don't understand your intent, nor fully the data structure, so I don't know why this is necessary.  I can say that if you want one row per order, then I would expect `orders.id` to be in the `group by`.

Comment: thanks for the reply. however this still returns the same

Comment: @IonasSkopelitis-Scholte . . . I removed `status_id`.  It is different on different rows and you only seem to want the largest value.